# Vagrant - Inline scripts on Windows throw '/bin/sh: sudo: command not found' error

Tags: vagrant, sudo

I'm running Vagrant on mac OS, setting up a Windows 7 VM. This is the provision script I am using at the moment:

```
 config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "C:/Users/IEUser/Downloads/launch.bat"
```

Every time I do this, or in fact any other inline command, it will cause the following to happen:

```
default: Running provisioner: shell...
default: Running: inline script
==> default: /bin/sh: sudo: command not found
```

This will happen no matter what inline script I use. Basically what I am trying to do is start a .bat file on the Virtual Machine when I do vagrant up or vagrant provision, but nothing I have tried is working.

Answer (score 1):

When you use [inline](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html#inline-scripts) option, vagrant will expect the content of the script itself.

If you reference an existing script you want to use [path](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html#path) option

> Path to a shell script to upload and execute. It can be a script relative to the project Vagrantfile or a remote script

Note that it **must** be relative to the project Vagrantfile, so from your host, not relative in the VM

Lets say you have the `launch.bat` file in a `script` directory within your host project folder, you will have

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "script/launch.bat"
```

Comment: Hi, this gives me the same error:  ==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /var/folders/bx/47f0tdgj6gx4t6vf3w6h05h40000gn/T/vagrant-shell20160824-7542-xhj7o5.bat
==> default: /bin/sh: sudo: command not found

Comment: hum .. thats weird I have windows box and it works fine. can you run your bat script if you logged in directly in windows ?

Comment: Yeah there are no problems at all when running directly from Windows.

Comment: can you just try something lame like `config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "dir c:"` and see if it works as expected

Comment: Exact same error with that command, all shell inline stuff causes the same error. I've also tried this on both a Windows 7 and Windows 8 box with two different hosts, one running here on Mac OS and one running and Windows 7. Same error across the board.

Comment: cupple of things : can you share the whole Vagrantfile ? is the box you used available somewhere so your issue can be replicated ? can you run `vagrant provision --debug` and show the interesting part before the error